# I have three versions of Android SDK Manager Installed. How can I consolidate them correctly?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am using Eclipse to develop an Android application and I noticed that over the years I've managed to acquire at least three versions of the Android SDK Manager (which obviously means other files as well). Please note that when I run the different SDK Managers individually, the current versions of various files installed differs and so I've kept them all updated. Obviously this can become a hassle when major updates come out and I spend an hour patching everything.

I'll do my best to describe everything I can including windows uninstall/change program information, installation locations, start menu indexing, project references, and eclipse references: (there are no windows PATH references to android sdk files)

- According to the Windows add/change programs menu, there is only one installation of Android SDK Tools
- I've managed to find android SDK files in:

  - C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\
  - C:\Users\Blake\android-sdks\ , and
  - C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\ (this installation contains uninstall.exe, and presumably was installed most recently as well)
- Indexed in the start menu (searching for sdk manager in start menu) is:

  - C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe
  - C:\Users\Blake\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe
- References in my Android Application's Properties:

  - Android tab: References appcompat v7 library in C:\Users\Blake\android-sdks\
  - Java Build Path tab: Libraries tab: Google APIs Android 4.3, using android.jar, effects.jar, usb.jar, maps.jar from C:\Users\Blake\android-sdks\ (Side question, how do I update this to use Google APIs Android 4.4?)
- References in Eclipse Preferences Menu

  - Android tab: SDK Location: C:\Users\Blake\android-sdks

As you can see, the SDK used by android and eclipse is C:\Users\Blake\android-sdks. Is this the "correct" one I should be using? Is it safe to delete the other two?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK can be anywhere on your hard drive. So you can safely delete the ones that are not used.
Also you can update your PATH variable in your Environment Variables to include the tools folder.

Comment: Thanks - uninstalling the SDK's in AppData and Program Files succeeded without incurring any problems.